# text-align: center isn't working

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

For some strange reason, my `text-align: center;` isn't working. It's weird 'cause it's the most basic stuff to do for both HTML and developer, so I'm kind of embarrassed... I must doing something terrible wrong and don't see my mistake. The `text-align` option isn't even showing in Firebug.

Could anyone help me out here?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-menu">
    <ul id="main-menu-links" class="links clearfix">
       <li class="menu-286 first active">
          <a class="active" title="" href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
       </li>
       <li class="menu-194">
         <a href="Organisation">Organisation</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:** (I have tried to place `text-align: center` in each selector, but with no result...)

```
div#main-menu {
    background-color: #c4d82d;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

div#main-menu ul {
    padding: 0px;
}

div#main-menu li{
    border-right: 1px solid #86a43f;
    width: 186px;
}

div#main-menu li.last{
    border: none;
}

div#main-menu a, div#main-menu a.active {
    background: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}

div#main-menu a:hover {
    background: none;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @greut I'm trying to give the links a `text-align: center`

Comment: @JudeArasu nope, I'm using Firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working as intended, when I wrap the `<ul>...</ul>` elements in a `<div id="main-menu">`:
http://jsfiddle.net/6bBK5/

Make sure that you use the correct selectors. IDs are case-sensitive, spaces in the selector are significant.

Comment: Exactly my thought. But something is blocking the element I guess. Still no results...

Comment: Can you show a link to your whole page? If not, check whether these selectors are clean: `#main-menu-links .links .clearfix .active .menu-194`. Also make sure that all of the CSS declarations **end with a semicolon (`;`)**.

Comment: It's a local dev-site, so no link is possible. It's really strange... I pasted the CSS link from Firebug, nothing. I used the `!important` selector, nothing... I can't make sense of it!

Comment: @Michiel Copy-paste the (generated) source code to http://pastebin.com/, http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. I did it, and all answers given here solved my problem. It's a Drupal website, so I'm guessing some other selector is blocking mine.

Comment: @Michiel There's not such as a "blocking" selector. If you increase the speficity of your selectors, the styles will be applied. If you show the generated HTML+CSS code of your page at http://jsbin.com/, I can have a look at it, and find the cause. If you prefer, you can also use http://pastebin.com/, at which you can set an expiry date, so that the code will disappear after a given time.

Comment: I'm not afraid about showing my code, but it's a massive number of CSS lines since I'm using a bunch of files. So if you are sure you want to shuffle you way through it, I'll be very thankful, but you don't need to do that.

Comment: With the right [tools](http://getfirebug.com/), I can identify the cause within a minute. (Firefox -> Firebug, Chrome -> Developer tools).

Comment: Ok, let me check once more. A matter of not getting depressed after such a blunder :) I'll be in touch

Comment: Ok Rob, thanks for following this issue to the end! Their was a hidden `width` somewhere is a CSS-file. So, it was my mistake :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <span>
        <ul>
              <li>Here is the centered Title!</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {text-align: center;}
li {display:inline; padding:0 10px 0 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, is working:

```
div#main-menu li{
    border-right: 1px solid #86a43f;
    width: 186px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: you must have other rules overriding it. If it works with `!important` you are ;-)